# Resolving dependencies in a reference assembly in a .net core console application

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm testing a small console application which will be used to display information based on a Quartz queue and I'm struggling to the the dependency to resolve within a reference assembly.

My console application references an EventData class, which has a dependency on IUtilities, within an assembly called App.Monitor, it's partial'ed as the base is code generated, and we're adding these properties / methods to the class for specific reasons...

```
public partial class EventData
{
    private readonly IUtilities _utilities;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime? DateStamp => _utilities?.Epoch(Timestamp);

    [JsonIgnore]
    public EventType EventType =>
        (EventType)EventType.Parse(typeof(EventType), (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Event)));

    public EventData(IUtilities utitlies)
    {
        _utilities = utitlies;
    }
}
```

In my console application I set up .net core dependency injection per various examples on the net, code for reference:

```
public IServiceProvider BuildDependencies()
{
    services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddTransient<IUtilities, Utilities>();

    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

Then somewhere in the console application, I'm doing a call that should initiate this dependency in utilities, which it doesn't do, IUtilities is always NULL:

```
provider.GetRequiredService<IUtilities>(); // thought this would fix it...

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QuartzJobs>>(json);    
var stamp = list[0].EventData.DateStamp;
```

**Update**

QuartzJobs (code generated)

```
public class QuartzJobs 
{
    [JsonProperty("event-data")]
    public EventData EventData { get; set; }
}
```

EventData (code generated)

```
public partial class EventData
{
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public double Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

EventData (partial'ed with custom logic)

```
public partial class EventData
{
    private readonly IUtilities _utilities;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime? DateStamp => _utilities?.Epoch(Timestamp);

    [JsonIgnore]
    public EventType EventType =>
        (EventType)EventType.Parse(typeof(EventType), (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Event)));

    public EventData(IUtilities utitlies)
    {
        _utilities = utitlies;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `EventData` initialized? where do you call the constructor that takes the dependency?

Comment: @Nkosi EventData is a property on QuartzJobs ( a class ), with a property that returns the value from EventData class when the user requests the DateStamp (per my last block of code.)

Comment: This works when I go through an ASP.Net Core controller, just with the console application is does not

Comment: Then it means that the default constructor is being called and not the one you defined in the partial.

Comment: that's what i through as well, yet the partial class constructor is called successfully when i do list[0].EventData.DateStamp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console you would need to take over the role of the framework and get the dependency and call the desired member

```
var utility = provider.GetRequiredService<IUtilities>();

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QuartzJobs>>(json);    

var stamp = utility?.Epoch(list[0].EventData.Timestamp);
```

That is because the container/provider is not the one resolving the `EventData`, so nothing is being injected.

Comment: that's what i'm doing in the interim, yes. that kind of breaks the pattern, if you will :(